# Font rendering issue with Word 2011 and 3rd party font (Admiration Pains)

Tags: macos, ms-office, font

I downloaded the [Admiration Pains](http://www.dafont.com/admiration-pains.font) font, installed it via Font Book, and verified it works fine in applications like Adobe CS and TextEdit. Unfortunately, when I try to use the font in Microsoft Word 2011, the font renders as some generic font (e.g. Times New Roman).  When I highlight the text, Word still reports the font family as Admiration Pains.

Things I've tried with no success:

1. Restarting Word;
2. Deleting the Font Cache file and restarting Word;
3. Changing font size;
4. Looked for "enabled duplicates" in Font Book;
5. Confirmed font is enabled in Font Book and that it Validates w/out issue;
6. Using [Font Nuke](http://jamapi.com/pr/fn/) to remove all caches of fonts and restarting computer.

Any ideas on how I can get this font to render properly in Word?

Here's a screenshot of the font trying to be used, where it renders fine in the font drop down, but not in the document:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

My workaround was to use [FontForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fontforge/) to open the TTF file and then re-generate the font family in TrueType format. Now Word 2011 shows it correctly.